# How to Calculate Nothing - Nil on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, spree

Rails 4, Spree 2.1

**The Issue:**

Adding an item to cart with the Spree Flexi Variants engraving calculator, I get an error:

```
 undefined method `value' for nil:NilClass
```

Is this line in my engraving calculator model causing this error?

```
def compute(product_customization, variant=nil)
  return 0 unless valid_configuration? product_customization

  # expecting only one CustomizedProductOption
  opt = product_customization.customized_product_options.detect {|cpo| cpo.customizable_product_option.name == "inscription" } rescue ''
  opt.value.length * (preferred_price_per_letter || 0)
end

def valid_configuration?(product_customization)
  true
end
```

And as for the value method, any ideas on that?

I've tried defining value but nothing seems to work. I have another calculator called *amount times contant*. This is setup pretty much the same way; however, this one works. Getting kind of confused and way past my deadline.

**Here is the github repo with the branch that I am using:** https://github.com/jsqu99/spree_flexi_variants/tree/spree-2-1-wip

**Trace:**

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `value' for nil:NilClass)
/Users/russellkompinski/Desktop/spree_commerce/spree_flexi_variants/app/models/spree/calculator/engraving.rb:29:in `compute'
/Users/russellkompinski/Desktop/spree_commerce/spree_flexi_variants/app/models/spree/product_customization.rb:11:in `price'
/Users/russellkompinski/Desktop/spree_commerce/spree_flexi_variants/app/models/spree/order_contents_decorator.rb:32:in `block in add_to_line_item'
/Users/russellkompinski/Desktop/spree_commerce/spree_flexi_variants/app/models/spree/order_contents_decorator.rb:32:in `map'
/Users/russellkompinski/Desktop/spree_commerce/spree_flexi_variants/app/models/spree/order_contents_decorator.rb:32:in `add_to_line_item'
/Users/russellkompinski/Desktop/spree_commerce/spree_flexi_variants/app/models/spree/order_contents_decorator.rb:7:in `add'
/Users/russellkompinski/Desktop/spree_commerce/spree_flexi_variants/app/models/spree/order_populator_decorator.rb:36:in `attempt_cart_add'
/Users/russellkompinski/Desktop/spree_commerce/spree_flexi_variants/app/models/spree/order_populator_decorator.rb:17:in `block in populate'
/Users/russellkompinski/Desktop/spree_commerce/spree_flexi_variants/app/models/spree/order_populator_decorator.rb:16:in `each'
/Users/russellkompinski/Desktop/spree_commerce/spree_flexi_variants/app/models/spree/order_populator_decorator.rb:16:in `populate'
/Users/russellkompinski/Desktop/spree_commerce/spree_flexi_variants/app/controllers/spree/orders_controller_decorator.rb:18:in `populate'
```

Comment: Your method `compute` returns `0` or `nil`. Are you sure that is what you want?

Comment: no it's not. But this somehow works with the other calculator and still returns a value.

Comment: If I delete the line and return without the condition, I receive "Spree::ProductCustomization can't be coerced into Fixnum"

Comment: Oh I see, that was only part of the method. Can you show the rest of your `compute` method?

Comment: @zwippie, just updated post with all compute method

Answer (score 2):

The source code you pointed to on github contains a different definition of `compute` as follows:

[image]

which is consistent with your stack trace, since line 29 of `engraving.rb` involves an invocation of `value`. I'm not familiar with spree, but based on this code, the `detect` call is returning `nil`.

Comment: Thanks @Peter.  But after update, still receiving the same error

Comment: I didn't mean to suggest that updating would fix anything. :-)

Comment: I was running something different on line 29, in which I didn't include the '|| 0' So I thought maybe without the 0, I was getting nil. So I tried adding the line that was different.

Comment: Oh, ok. Well, anyway, the problem is with `opt` being `nil`, not with anything else going on in that line. Do you understand why it's being assigned `nil` in line 28?

Comment: I don't understand why that is, exactly. It appears that way in the spree doc examples and other calculator examples, they all seem do it. I thought it had do with something regarding the 0 vs nil thing that I've come acrossed a few times. My mind can't comprehend nothing, maybe. Can you inform me?

Comment: The other calculator here, the one that does work uses the same: https://github.com/jsqu99/spree_flexi_variants/blob/spree-2-1-wip/app/models/spree/calculator/amount_times_constant.rb

Comment: And the spree docs seems to imply it here, when they use object=nil: http://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/calculators.html

Comment: I'm going to work on trying to hackup the amount_times_constant to behave the way I want it. Thanks for your time. I won't take anymore of it.

Comment: I don't mind helping because I answer SO questions to force myself to learn about things I otherwise might not learn about. Anyway, I'm not suggesting there is anything wrong with that `compute` method. The example you pointed to is passing `nil` in. That's not what you're doing, though, right?

Comment: It is basically. All I really am trying to achieve is to be able to calculate the fields to add up a total. So I wanted to have the calculators work the way they're intended to, only I was going to change the engraving from * val.length where it counts each letter and sums, to compute only the field as a whole.. The amount calculator is acting funky and I get different computations every other time. It's weird. So basically I was going to keep messing until it hopefully works

Comment: I just came across google group from a post from Ryan Bigg. "If something goes wrong, an exception should be raised (and rescued)

If the calculator is called and some criteria doesn't match, it should return 0 as it should not modify the order. If it returns nil, then Spree will attempt to add nil to a Float and that never ends well."

Comment: The link to that is: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/spree-user/AlVdkBeRk5k/BbPSQjmq9DcJ

Comment: Ok, that's fine, but this `compute` method clearly expects there to be exactly one `inscription` option. Is that not ensured by your code?

Comment: Ok, I see that `create_options` in the same `engraving.rb` file ensures that. So the question is why is the argument to `compute` not getting initialized and maintained properly.

Comment: Well, i started trying to achieve this with the amount times constant calculator. Now I get no implicit conversion of BigDecimal into String when I try to edit the compute to opt.to_s + preferred_multiplier

Comment: which I guess becomes a whole other issue

Comment: You're losing me here. I have no idea how Spree customization/configuration works. What are you doing to enable use of the engraving calculator? In any event, I think you need to see what the value of `product_customization` is that is getting passed in to this `compute` method when it fails. For instance, you could add a line `puts product_customization.inspect if opt.nil?` right before the `opt.value ...` line.

Comment: Well if i run that before the compute block i receive: The single-table inheritance mechanism failed to locate the subclass: 'Spree::Calculator::Engraving'. This error is raised because the column 'type' is reserved for storing the class in case of inheritance.

Comment: I'm looking into that more now

Comment: What do you mean by "before the compute block"? Did you place it where I suggested (i.e. right before the line that raised the error)?

Comment: i did put it there, but it didn't change anything

Comment: Did it not print out the value of `product_customization`?

Comment: Sorry, but that just doesn't make sense. Why don't you go ahead and remove the `if obj.nil?` clause and just make it `puts "In compute, obj = #{obj.inspect}"`

Comment: hey man thanks for all your insight. I just got done with what I was trying to achieve! =)